# Flutter: Scrollable widgets with StreamBuilder widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two main widget in my screen. First i used Column do display them both. First widget is Table Calendar and second one is StreamBuilder that uses LisView.builder to display information from FireStore in Card. In this state only the StreamBuilder with ListView is scrollable. How can i make an entire page scrollable?

This how my widgets set:

```
Scaffold
 -SafeArea
  -Column
   -calendar()
   -Expanded
    -StreamBuilder
     -ListView.builder
      -Card
```

Comment: use `CustomScrollView` with two slivers: `SliverToBoxAdapter` and `SliverList`

Comment: i'm having the same problem, have u already found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your column inside a `SingleChildScrollView` and set `shrinkWrap` to `true` and `physics` to `NeverScrollingPhysic` for your `ListView`.

Comment: I added it, but my screen show nothing(black) and i got this in terminal: 'Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out'

Comment: OP uses `ListView.builder`, not `ListView` - probably to build only visible items and not all of them

Comment: You're right. In that case it's not a good solution @pskink